# How to filter data from database based on YYYY-MM using Selection and SelectionArgs[] parameter in Android SQLite Query

Tags: sqlite, datetime, android-activity, android-sqlite

I am storing YYYY-MM-DD and HH:MM:SS values in two separate columns in all my SQLite tables.

I have been using the following code to filter data by supplier id and date from my SQLite database.

```
    public double addPurchaseTotal(String supplierID, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    double result = 0;
    String selection = VivzHelper.COLUMN_ADD_PURCHASE_SUPPLIER_ID + " =? "
            + " AND " + VivzHelper.COLUMN_ADD_PURCHASE_DATE + " =? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = {supplierID, date};
    Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.ADD_PURCHASE_TABLE,
            new String[]{"sum(" + VivzHelper.COLUMN_ADD_PURCHASE_ITEM_COST_PRICE + ")"},
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        result = c.getDouble(0);
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

The value for date parameter is obtained from a date picker. As mentioned earlier, date value under the `VivzHelper.COLUMN_ADD_PURCHASE_DATE` is stored in YYYY-MM-DD format. I would like to filter my data based on YYYY-MM (year and month alone). How can this be done?

Comment: Write WHERE clause in the selection query and pass the arguments for the selection query in the selectionArgs using a String array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing the entire string with `=`, check for the prefix with [LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) or GLOB:

```
... WHERE Supplier = 'xxx' AND Date LIKE '2015-04-%'
... WHERE Supplier = 'xxx' AND Date GLOB '2015-04-*'
```

(GLOB works better together with indexing.)

In Java:

```java
String selection = ...
        + " AND " + VivzHelper.COLUMN_ADD_PURCHASE_DATE + " GLOB ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { ..., date.substring(0, 8) + "*" };
```

Comment: LIKE/GLOB makes sense. I tried different ways. But still failing to understand and frame the statement. I am yet to settle between using the above syntax of code used in my question and `SELECT Title FROM Book WHERE Desc LIKE '%cat%";` or **your** kind of code posted by you. Contd...

Comment: Contd... **I am a beginner**. I know this is too much in asking. But, could you please frame the **LIKE/GLOB** in **1.** my above code that was posted in the question, **2.** frame a similar query statement using `SELECT Title FROM Book WHERE Desc LIKE '%cat%";` kind of stat. and **3.** frame a similar query statement using `...Where Supplier =...` . I am not asking this for receiving a copy-paste kind of answer. I only want to understand how to use different coding methods to frame a LIKE/GLOB statement. This is only for my understanding. Please don't down vote my question/comment. Thanks u

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this: [SQLite Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)